# Finding two new vectors on a plane with angles theta and -theta

Tags: three.js

I have a vector V on a `ThreeJS` plane. And I need to draw 2 vectors V1 and V2 with the following conditions.

- The angle between V1 and V is *theta*.
- The angle between V2 and V is *-theta*.

V1 and V2 are defined with Point P1 as origin. How do I find the position of V1 and V2 with the specified angles wrt the center line?

[image]

Comment: If you know the normal of the plane, then you can rotate `V` around it, using [`.applyAxisAngle( normal, angle )`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.applyAxisAngle)

Comment: formatted the texts

Comment: Sounds like you want to draw a cone?

Comment: Actually, no I don't want to draw a cone. I just need to find the position of the vector points v1 and v2 . Apologies for the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to write it in code, but in mathematics you would use the theta's to find v, then finding v1 and v2 in relation (taking tan(theta))